# Stencyl -- get more than one value from a Map

Tags: dictionary, stencyl

How can I get all 3 values from a Map with the key "2" ?
Right now it takes always the last one from any number, for example if i type in "1" it will take the last letter of it "f".

Is it because there is no loop ?

[image]

[image: MAPS]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, it is not possible to directly store multiple values with the same key in Stencyl, nor in any programming language. Each value will overwrite the previous one, which is why your `2` key is returning `i`. Instead, you could consider these workarounds:

1. Name your keys `0a`, `0b`, `0c`, `1a`, `1b`, `1c`, and so on. It's pretty simple to get the values with this method.
2. Store your values in a single key, separated by commas. E.g. key `0` is `a,b,c`, `1` is `d,e,f`, and so on. Then you can use the **list** blocks with `split (value of 0 for TT) using separator ,` to get the 3 values (which will be `a`, `b` and `c`).

If you have any questions about either of these methods, don't hesitate to ask!